# How Do I Disconnect This Plastic Wire Connector?

Tags: wiring

I am trying to disassemble my Kenmore Elite clothes dryer so I can test the thermal fuse. I need to disconnect wires that are held together with a plastic wire connector. Can anyone tell me how I get this specific connector to disconnect? (See pic in link) Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Additional pictures from other angles, and in focus, would be very helpful.

Comment: Most likely a tab or latch needs to be pried up and then it will pull apart. Better pictures of both sides would help get you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are little hooks inside the connector (from the wire side). You have to find something small. (Tiny screwdriver) Push these hooks down and that releases the wire. If you are careful you can connect them again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a “molex” brand connector some do have anti vibration locks. In many cases that some arcing has welded them together I cut each wire on the “left” side and wire but then do the same to the right  side , some times the male / female pins have arced , other times at one of the connectors, if you can’t release it some times with a catch it may be welded and cutting and re connecting may be the best and cheapest way forward.